# multiple drop down issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a drop down menu which has certain items(keys) in it and corresponding to that there is a txt box(for values) user can add multiple such drop down menus on the UI by clicking a button. As a result, after selecting a key on a drop down, the identical key should be hidden in the consequent drop down list. I am kind of stuck at it.

here is the code:

```
   <fieldset id="filter_parts">
   <div class="filter_chunk filter_piece" id="filter_chunk_1">
      <select class="span-4 ui-input parameter" name="filterProperty" id="filterProperty">
         <c:forEach var="message" items="${multiValueSearch}">
            <option value='<c:out value="${message.name}"/>' label='<c:out value="${message.name}"/>'>
               <c:out value="${message.name}"/>
            </option>
         </c:forEach>
      </select>
      <input class="span-4 text" id="filterBy" name="filterBy" type="text"/>
      <span class="button remove_btn" id="remove_1" onclick="remove_filter(this)" class="removable" >
         <img alt="Remove" src="
         <c:url value="/static/images/icon_remove.png"/>
         " title="Remove" />
      </span>
      <span class="button addParamBtn" id="add_filter_part" onclick="add_filter()"  >
         <img alt="Add" src="
         <c:url value="/static/images/icon_add.png" />
         " title="Add More" />
      </span>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD5C1.png)

Comment: Can you show us what have you worked on the JavaScript front?

Comment: the drop down cannot be hidden, you can achieve it by removing the subsequent drop down list.